# Parse multiple JSON objects in one file

Tags: java, json, gson

I have multiple `JSON` objects stored in one file separated by new line character (but one object can span over multiple lines) - it's an output from `MongoDB` shell.

What is the easiest way to parse them (get them in an array or collection) using `Gson` and `Java`?

Comment: There are parsers that can handle this, by leaving the input stream positioned at the end of the prior object/array when there may be more than one.  But there are 20-30 different JSON kits for Java, so I can't say which have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use Jackson and its [ObjectReader.readValues()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValues%28byte[]%29) methods:

```
public <T> Iterator<T> readStream(final InputStream _in) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // configure object mappings
    ...
    // and then
    return mapper.reader(MapObject.class).readValues(_in);
}
```

works pretty good on big enough (few gigabytes) JSON datafiles